# C# parse Apple formatted strings (printf)

Tags: c#, printf, string.format

I'm dealing some with Apple formatted strings, for example:

```
[%d] fsPurgeable type: %@, count: %lld bytes for %lld files
```

According to Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), the format string specification follows the `IEEE printf specification`, with some modifications it appears.

I need to parse these strings, and replace the % type placeholders with the actual data that belongs there.  My initial thought was to use a Regex, however as these claim to adhere to `printf` specifications, I was wondering if there was anything already in .net that might help with this.

I've done some reading, but I can't see anything that immediately jumped out as useful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: F# uses printf formatting - perhaps you could use that implementation from your c#... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091256/call-f-printfn-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To somewhat answer my own question, I ended up writing a regex to handle the parsing:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?i)%[dspublicxfegahztj{}@%]*");
```

(?i) = case insensitive flag

% = literal percent sign

[dspublicxfegahztj{}@%] = all valid characters that could follow the %

* = match zero or multiple characters, e.g. %lld

Still curious if there is anything in .Net to handle this sort of thing

Comment: Here is a regex that's a bit more faithful to the specification: `(%[-+ #]*(\d+|\*)?(.\d+|.\*)?(hh|h|l|ll|j|z|t|L|I|I32|I64|w)?[%csdioxXufFeEaAgGp]|%n)`